# QGIS geographic grid

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, grids-graticules

I need to know why my geographic grid it is not 37mm / 3,7 cm, I guess this bug or somethings is not true, I need to print grid with 30" interval and 37mm length of grid in milimetre.

[image: screeshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

```
QGIS version
3.22.3-Białowieża
QGIS code revision
1628765ec7
Qt version
5.15.2
Python version
3.9.5
Compiled against GDAL/OGR
3.4.0
Running against GDAL/OGR
3.4.1
Compiled against PROJ
8.2.0.%3.%4
Running against PROJ
8.2.1
EPSG Registry database version
v10.041 (2021-12-03)
GEOS version
3.10.0-CAPI-1.16.0
SQLite version
3.35.2
PDAL version
2.3.0
PostgreSQL client version
13.0
SpatiaLite version
5.0.1
QWT version
6.1.3
QScintilla2 version
2.11.5
OS version
Windows 10 Version 2009




Active Python plugins
db_manager
0.1.20
grassprovider
2.12.99
MetaSearch
0.3.5
processing
2.12.99
sagaprovider
2.12.99
```

Comment: 37 mm in real life, or on the map canvas?

Comment: in map canva for printable

Comment: Just put lines across your map canvas, spaced 37 mm apart.

Comment: Must change the scale of the map item accordingly. For example, 25022 at equator.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca, oke thanks let me try